# I have a image for social icon in footer, i want it to change its background color on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button for social icon in footer, i want it to change its background color on hover. 
i am putting it in a class social and in my css i give that on hover it should change its background color. Not working.

```
This is HTML for footer:

<div class="footer">
        <div class="container" align = "center">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block"data-toggle="modal"       href="#tallModal6">Click here "</button>
        </div>
        <div class="container social" align = "center" style = "color:white">

            <img src="images/fb.png" height = "50px" width = "50px" >
            <img src="images/gplus.png" height = "50px" width = "50px" >
            <img src="images/linkedin.png"  height = "50px" width = "50px" >
            <img src="images/mail.png"  height = "50px" width = "50px">
        </div>
        <div class="container" align = "center">

        </div>
    </div>
```

This is in my CSS:

```
.social:hover {

    background-color = white;
    }
```

Comment: background-color: white;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your css has some syntax errors.  This should work:

```
.social:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

The mistake was using an equals `=` sign instead of a colon `:`.

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp) on CSS syntax

Comment: Solved my problem! Thanks. I should die.. :|

Comment: Glad to have been able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

background-color = white is not a thing in CSS.

Should be like this:

```
.social:hover{background-color: white;}
```

**[Link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp)** for some help on CSS syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted the background color of the button to change, not the .social div, so you'll need to apply the CSS to that button.

http://jsfiddle.net/cqsq7bxd/

```
button:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

If you want it for the .social div, you can apply it like this:

```
.social:hover {
background-color: white;
}
```